# The link "pictures" is broken. Move it to Trash? This LInk cannot be used because its target"/home/-"Pictures" doesn't exist

Tags: files

I am not sure how this happened, but whenever I open the Files application, I see an error that reads:

```
The link {name} is broken. Move it to Trash?
```

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like the permissions in your home directory have been modified, denying you permission to the directories where those links point to. You may need to repair those directories in Terminal with a `chown -R user:user ~/Videos` (replacing `user:user` with the proper account and group) 

Comment: It is not only that. Links point to non existing targets, e.g. the link `Videos` -> `-Videos`. It would appear that the folders themselves have been deleted or moved.

Comment: how can i resolve this can u please help me

Comment: Can we help you? hardly. Now, if you [edit] the question and describe exactly what you did prior to noticing the problem then maybe, we'll see what can be done about it. In any case you should have backups if the data matters to you.